# Puppet Apply: Could not find class for

Tags: puppet, configuration-management

It seems pretty simple thing, and it works on Vagrant, but I can't make it work on a EC2 server.

When:

```
 puppet apply manifests/init.pp
```

Error:

```
 Could not find class base for s1.ec2.internal at /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/s1/workspace/manifests/init.pp:1 on node s1.ec2.internal
```

File `./manifests/init.pp:`

```
include base
```

File `./manifests/base.pp:`

```
class base {

  exec { "apt-get update":
    command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
    timeout => 0
  }

  package { ["vim", "git", "build-essential"]:
    ensure  => present,
    require => Exec["apt-get update"]
  }

}
```

Puppet v2.7.23

Answer (score 4):

Like Felix stated the class base is being looked for in the modules of your puppet manifests. The directory structure of your modules as follows:

```
$confdir/
|- manifests
   |- init.pp <- The file you reference to when executing puppet apply
|- modules
   |- base
      |- manifests
         |- init.pp <- The file containing your base class
```

What Felix forgot to mention was that there needs to be another manifests directory within the `base` module directory.

See also https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/modules_fundamentals.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually class `base` will be found only in a module named `base`.

Try putting it into `modules/base/init.pp` instead of `manifests/base.pp`.

Comment: I'm going to try it. But why does it work on vagrant (native precise64 puppet)?

Comment: I tried to move `manifests/base.pp` to `manifests/modules/base/init.pp` but did't work.

Comment: As stated, the `modules` tree must be on the same level as `manifests`, **not inside** `manifests/`. Vagrant may work during provisioning on the basis of some specifics, but those do not extend to `puppet apply` when used inside the machine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a permissions issue - the files were owned by root but I wasn't running puppet with `sudo`